# Space instead of leading 0 Date Java

Tags: java, date, formatting

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss"); 
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
    SimpleDateFormat sdff = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm:ss"); 
    System.out.println(sdff.format(new Date()));
```

Output is:

```
    Aug 04 10:58:55
    Aug 4 10:58:55
```

I want output to be:

```
    Aug 04 10:58:55
    Aug  4 10:58:55
```

Any ideas?

But if day has two numbers I need it to have one space:

```
    Aug 14 10:58:55
    Aug  4 10:58:55
```

Comment: current out put is same as what your are expecting...so no issue.. If you are bother about alignment, it is just a formatting issue.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Kami is looking for some "white-space padding" in a date formatter. Take a closer look.

Comment: It isn't I need `Aug  4`, getting `Aug 4`, one space instead of two. @dotvav Wont it make two spaces if there are two numbers tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are bother about white space just add a white space to formatter.

```
"MMM  d HH:mm:ss"
```

Eg:

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
int day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
if(day>9){
  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss");
}else{
  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM  d HH:mm:ss");
}
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Out put:

```
Aug  4 15:50:25
```

Comment: Wont work if there are two numbers in a day, so it will be `Aug  11`, while I need `Aug 11`. Formatting doesn't show it let me edit my question.

Comment: I see your edit, smart, no idea how I didn't think of it.

Comment: @Ruchira, now you are using deprecated APIs. I would rather have some other option than use them.

Comment: @Codebender yes. You can go with `Calendar` as my edit.

Comment: Just fix your output and I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK no pattern in `SimpleDateFormat` to do that.

The easiest way is the simplest. Check the string length and add an extra space if needed. Since all the other items have fixed length, there is no need for a more complicated check.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdff = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm:ss");
if (sdff.length == 14) {
   sdff = sdff.substring(0,4) + " " + sdff.substring(4);
}
```

If you want it fancy (aka RegExp), it is kind of a little more robust but not worth the effort IMO

```
SimpleDateFormat sdff = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d HH:mm:ss");
sdff = sdff.replaceAll(" (\\d) ", "  $1 ");
```

Comment: if the timezone is also in there, the length varies

Comment: I actually need this to parse. So I ended up just replacing all double spaces with space zero before giving to parse. `SDF_psql.parse("Thu Dec  1 13:05:44 SAST 2022".replaceAll("  "," 0"))`

Answer (score 2):

Check out this method of `SimpleDateFormat` class:

```
public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo,
                               FieldPosition pos) { ...}
```

and provide custom `FieldPosition` implementation.

Comment: Do you have any link that explains how `FieldPosition` works? I always have found it difficult to understand.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Would be glad if somebody finds it and posts here.